# CSS Fliping animation not working in IE 9 or 10

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple CSS flip animation which works in other major browsers, seems to be not working in IE 9.0 or 1.0 for some reasons.

jsbin handler.
http://jsbin.com/IQUqUBe/1/

Below is the links which i have looked upon.

1. https://github.com/vinothbabu/3DFlipper
2. http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

I am not able to figure out where is the issue whether its `z-index` or any other property which is causing this issue and also can you guys suggest on **how to debug CSS code if possible**.

Comment: You are expecting too much from IE

Comment: @Mr. Alien Without mentioning any specific problem, this kind of comment is just a troll. IE is not as bad as before, especially since version 10.

Comment: i too waiting for this asnwer.

Comment: @Kaidjin It's better, but still, IE sucks any time..

Comment: @Mr.Alien Prove it. And before you do, remember that i'm not saying you're wrong, just that your comment is useless.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: It should work in IE 10. IE is one of the browsers which led a great revolution back in 2000 era.

Comment: @Kaidjin You can prove it by making it work in IE 10 :) the point of the comment was IE unlike other browsers do no adapt the newer properties, it goes slow, it's not frequently updated, and if you must have heard, inorder to make websites more jazzy using CSS3, leave IE behind, no doubt 10 has a great support for new features, but that doesn't make a browser awesome, page loading, load balancing, smoothness, etc, IE lacks all, it's heavy compared to other browsers...and I guess I've made this thing before and did worked in IE, what it missed was backface visibility,I don't remember quiet well

Comment: @Mr.Alien : Agree IE is kinda slow but IE has many things right, the best example would be box-sizing - border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not that it does not work in IE 10. set a doctype at the top: `<!DOCTYPE html>` This will take IE out of quirks mode. Below is the fiddle for the same.

http://jsbin.com/IQUqUBe/3/edit

This should make the code to **work in IE**.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to **debuging CSS code** you can use developer tools.

- For **Firefox** the best solution would be [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
- for **Chrome**, developer tools are built-in. Simply press <kbd>F12</kbd>
- for **IE** there is [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is specifically, but here is a link saying that transition does not work in IE9: http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

If you go in the "issues" tab, you'll see that it doesn't work on any pseudo-elements beside :before and :after for IE10 (and others).

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, :hover is a pseudo class, and the link doesn't say that it doesn't work for IE10. I still don't know why it doesn't work.

Have you tried removing the `-ms-` prefix ? Apparently IE10 supports the transition without prefix.

Comment: Not on :hover elements. Look at the "issues" tab under the table.

Comment: :hover is not a pseudo _element_, it's a pseudo _class_. So this should not be the relevant issue here.

Comment: @CBroe good point. And it's true that his animation works on IE so the problem lies elsewhere...